# Массивы С++ Помогите

Tags: c++

Дано ціле число N (N<0). Сформувати і вивести цілочисельний масив разміру N, що містить ступені двійки від першої до N-ої: 2,4,8,16,..

Может кто подсказать как это реализовать?

Comment: Эмм... В цикле с умножением?

Comment: Да как угодно лиж бы понятно было как такое реализовать

Comment: У вас в названии вопроса запятой не хватает после С++  :))

Comment: Массивы отрицательной длинны, запрещены на C и C++. Решения не существует.

Comment: А N точно меньше нуля? :)

Comment: Виправте питання, дійсно поставлено некоректно, або відправте фото питання.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
           
   int main()
{
    int n;
    int temp = 1;
    cout << "Put integer value" << endl << "N:";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    int* array = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0) 
            array[i] = 1;
        else{

        array[i] = temp =2*temp;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout<<array[i]<<"\t";
    }
    delete[] array; `введите сюда код`
}
```

При условии, что `N` больше нуля. Ну и организуйте проверку на ввод целого числа. Я только учусь. Могу допускать ошибки.